# Monitoring all the child processes in C

Tags: c, process, waitpid

I have a question regarding process management in Unix.

Let's say I have a C program "main" which forks a child and wait for the child to finish using waitpid sys call.

The child process calls a script "test". The script "test" forks a child and exits. It does not wait for its child to finish. The child is taken up by init process and root becomes its Parent process. So this results into my "main" process to end.

The problem/question is - How do I keep track of all the processes spawned by my "main" program (including child, grandchild and child for which parent exited) ? In this specific case, I need my "main" to wait till the child forked by the script "test" is not completed.

I am stuck onto this problem. Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: If you’re on Linux you could check out [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/549018/can-a-process-adopt-a-grandchild-as-its-child)

Comment: I am on linux, but this answer mentions - "PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER " which is not available on many systems like RHEL, Centos etc.

Comment: It does require kernel 3.4 but I don’t see a specific reference to that feature not being available in RHEL and the like. Is it just an older system that you’re referring to?

Comment: It would be much better to provide an alternative answer. I am Using redhat and I do not have that option while using prctl command. I checked man page of prctl. It doesn't have it either.

Comment: Based on the explanation in that answer, it sounds like there is no portable way to do it. If you are imposing specific requirements of certain OS versions then you should put that in the question.

Comment: That's fine Morris. Please always suggest an answer which can be applied on generic cases. Also, it would be good if you show some snapshots on how it is happening with advantages and disadvantages to the solution you mentioned. Just an abstract comment like 'check out this answer'  will not help. You must be knowing that I had tried all of it before coming here to ask the question. Thanks